# Android cookies without CookieManager

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies

I know that a similar question is posted here: [Android Session cookies without using CookieManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502066/android-session-cookies-without-using-cookiemanager)
However, I can not get it to work.

```
 URL urlObj = new URL(urlPath);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

    if (urlPath.toLowerCase().startsWith("https:")) {
        initializeHttpsConnection((HttpsURLConnection) conn);
    }
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();
        // Send body data
        os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(bodyData);
        // Must flush and close to make sure all the data is sent.
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // Get response
        in = conn.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");

        String cookie = conn.getRequestProperty("Cookie");
```

//            Map> rp = conn.getRequestProperties();
            if (cookie != null && cookie.length() > 0)
            {
                _cookie = cookie;
                Log.v("cookie2", _cookie);
            }

"cookie" is always null.

However, if I do include CookieManger (and run it with 2.3.3+) then cookie has the required value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for http url con:

```
  while ((headerfields = connection.getHeaderField(i)) != null) {
          String key = connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
          if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("SET-COOKIE")) {
         ssss= (((key==null) ? "" : key + ": ") + headerfields);}
          i++;

          }
```

Comment: What would I expect in "ssss"?

Comment: its to store the cookie string

Comment: Great. So, the result is: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3B299C570A21D2A5E84673AC7718BA1C; Path=/cell   What part of it do I need to "send back" when doing setRequestProperty?

Comment: here 3B299C570A21D2A5E84673AC7718BA1C this is your session id or cookie